# Post and vote any of the days of Chanukah in Winterbash

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

Recently I saw the list of all hats. One hat has the description below:

> "Post and vote any of the days of Chanukah"

**List of hat link:**

http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com

What is meaning of this description, so that I can achieve this hat?

Comment: Dude, how many questions have you asked about the hats that were answered with _"read"_ and _"patience"_, now?

Comment: @Cerbrus see the reason in comment of Glorfindel answer that's why.

Comment: @Ironman even if I'm not logged in on the Winterbash site, I can click on the hat's description and see it.

Comment: all the description related to hat is already given just click on the hat to know more

Comment: Even on Meta posts are expected to demonstrate research. Possibly you don't have access to common engines wherever you are... Usually one would recommend Google, but since it is likely not accessible to you - try https://www.bing.com/search?q=days+of+Chanukah (or Yahoo, Rambler, Baidu or whatever is not blocked for you) than [edit] post with information that you found but could not understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Exactly as it says, all you need to do is:

> Post and vote any of the days of Chanukah

Chanukah begins in the evening of *Saturday, December 24* and ends in the evening of *Sunday, January 1*.

[Chanukah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanukkah):

> is a Jewish holiday commemorating the rededication of the Holy Temple (the Second Temple) in Jerusalem at the time of the Maccabean Revolt against the Seleucid Empire.

Comment: Great thanks for the information.

Answer (score 4):

You can click on the hat, it will show a longer description:

> ask, answer, or vote on any of the days of Chanukah starting December 24-Jan 1

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I am not using `StackExchange` site so it give me no description and ask for adding detail that's why I don't knew it.